# Formula for all the Lorentz boosts that result in $E$ parallel to $B$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, reference-frames, classical-electrodynamics

This is a follow-up question to a [previous question regarding a minimum-energy invariant of the electromagnetic field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/468153/is-there-a-special-inertial-frame-determined-by-the-value-of-e-and-b-at-a-poin).  @ChiralAnomaly showed that there is indeed an invariant minimum energy density whenever $E\cdot B \not= 0$; and that there is a one-parameter family of inertial frames in which $E$ and $B$ are parallel.  In those frames the energy density *is* the minimum energy density, and is the same in all of them.

The minimum energy density is easy enough to calculate.  Is there a straightforward way to derive a formula that, given $E$ and $B$ in one frame, yields all the Lorentz boosts that result in $E$ parallel to $B$?

Answer (score 2):

We need a Lorentz transformation which will make $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ from inertial frame $S$ parallel in an inertial frame $S'$, i.e. $\vec{E'} \times \vec{B'} = 0$. Consider $c=1$ for calculations.

Let us try $\vec{v'} = \alpha (\vec{E} \times \vec{B})$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}/\{0\}$. Here, $v'$ denotes the velocity of the frame $S'$ with respect to $S$.

Then, $$\vec{E'} = \gamma(\vec{E}+\vec{v'}\times\vec{B}) = (1 - \alpha B^2) \vec{E}+\alpha (\vec{E} \cdot \vec{B}) \vec{B} \\ 
\vec{B'} = \gamma(\vec{B}-\vec{v'}\times\vec{E}) = (1 - \alpha E^2) \vec{B}+\alpha (\vec{E} \cdot \vec{B}) \vec{E}$$

**Case 1 (a)**: Of course, as you mentioned, if $\vec{E} \cdot \vec{B} = 0$ and $|\vec{E}|=|\vec{B}|=0$, $\vec{E'}$ and $\vec{B'}$ cannot be made parallel.

**Case 1 (b)**: Even if $\vec{E} \cdot \vec{B} = 0$, but $E^2 \ne B^2$, we can make either $\vec{E'}$ or $\vec{B'}$ zero, by choosing $\alpha = \displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{max}(E^2, B^2)}$

**Case 2**: Suppose, $\vec{E} \cdot \vec{B} \ne 0$, then $\vec{E'}$ and $\vec{B'}$ can be made parallel by choosing an $\alpha$ such that $$\alpha^2 [(\vec{E} \cdot \vec{B})^2 - E^2B^2] = 1 - \alpha(E^2+B^2).$$ The relative velocity $\vec{v'}$ of the frame $S'$ with respect to the inertial frame $S$ is given by 
$$\frac{\vec{v'}}{1+ v'^2} = \frac{\alpha(\vec{E}\times\vec{B})}{1+\alpha^2({\vec{E}\times \vec{B}})^2} = \frac{\alpha (\vec{E}\times \vec{B})}{1+\alpha^2[E^2B^2-(\vec{E} \cdot \vec{B})^2]}= \frac{\vec{E}\times\vec{B}}{E^2+B^2}.$$

Comment: In your equations for E' and B', should the v be primed?

Comment: and by max(a,b) do you mean the greater of a and b?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Updated to $v'$. And by $\text{max}(a,b)$, I mean whichever is greater.

Comment: The formulas you've given provide one inertial frame in which E and B are parallel.  But there is a continuum of such inertial frames, corresponding to *further* boosts in the direction of E (or B) in the frame you've identified.  What I'm hoping for is a formula that provides *all* such frames (neglecting spatial rotations of coordinates), as a function of a single parameter.

Comment: I see. I don't know how to formulate that parameter. This question got more interesting for me. I'll update my answer once I work it out in the coming summer vacation.

Comment: Two notes : First, the velocity $\vec{v'}$ in your equations must be unprimed since it is that of the system S' with respect to S. It's a vector in S. Second, making the hypothesis that $\:\vec v=\alpha(\vec E \times\vec B)\:$ is the reason for missing the fact that there exists a continuous 1-parametric set of solutions (boosts) with velocities $\vec{\mathrm w}$ not parallel to $\:(\vec E \times\vec B)$, see my answer here [Wigner Rotation of static E & M fields is dizzying](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/460253/wigner-rotation-of-static-e-m-fields-is-dizzying/462148#462148).